# why am i getting a fatal error when i run this code?

Tags: php, global

```
<?php
if (ini_get('auto_globals_jit'))
    // Override setting
    $GLOBALS+=['_ENV'=>$_ENV,'_REQUEST'=>$_REQUEST];
    
// Sync PHP globals with corresponding hive keys
$this->init=$this->hive;
foreach (explode('|',self::GLOBALS) as $GLOBALS) {
    $sync=$this->sync($GLOBALS);
    $this->init+=[
        $GLOBALS=>preg_match('/SERVER|ENV/',$GLOBALS)?$sync:[]
    ];
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! could you provide the error message when you run this code?

Comment: Under PHP 8, I am getting _"Fatal error: $GLOBALS can only be modified using the $GLOBALS[$name] = $value syntax"_ regarding the `$GLOBALS+=...` line. If that is what you are talking about - well then your "why" is right there.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the error message there instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`$GLOBALS` is a PHP created Array, you can alter it but alter it like you would an existing Assoc array. So

```
$GLOBALS['_ENV'] = $_ENV;
```

Although if you simply do

```
$_ENV = 'Something'
```

then $_ENV will now be in the $GLOBALS array, so there is really no reason to amend it directly.

> For reference [The manual on $GLOCALS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)